# Fixing X11's startup Errors by Xorg.conf or modprobe

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, xorg, xorg.conf, modprobe

I am using Ubuntu Live CD to get an access to the broken Ubuntu after running a few [Linux Kernel Magic commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) without knowing completely what I did.
I mounted the system to Live CD.

I need to apparently be able to run aptitude such that I can fix the following errors in my T60s.

```
(EE) intel(0): Failed to set tiling on front buffer: rejected by kernel
(EE) intel(0): Failed to set tiling on back buffer: rejected by kernel
(EE) intel(0): Failed to set tiling on depth buffer: rejected by kernel
(EE) XKB: No component provided Virtual core keyboard
```

## #1 solution: Xorg.conf

### #1.1

I run replaced the xorg.conf with the backup files at /mnt/sda5/etc/xorg.conf unsuccessfully. My T60s still goes to the gray-error screen although I use different xorg.conf -files.

I booted my system by Cmd-Alt-SysRq {r,e,i,s,u,b} so the new xorg.conf should be in the mounted sda5.

#1.2

I removed my /etc/X11/xorg.conf, but the same problem remains.
This suggests to me that the problem is not in X11.

## #2 Solution

Daubers at Ubuntu-uk suggests to

1. mount /proc /dev /sys into your old fs using a loopback interface
2. run chroot

This means that I need to run

```
   mount /dev/sda5 /proc 
   mount /dev/sda5 /dev 
   mount -o loop /chroot/sys /sys
```

The last command gives me the output

```
could not find any loop device. Maybe this kernel does not know about the loop device? (if so, recomplie or `modprobe loop`.)
```

The [output means apparently](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Flinux.ilmainen.net%2Fkonsoli.htm&sl=fi&tl=en) that Ubuntu's Linux Kernel does not support the feature *loop*.

The command `fdisk -l` gives me:

[image]

**How can you run `mount -o loop /chroot/sys` successfully?**
I need to apparently add some module to Linux kernel

## #3 by Ubuntu Live CD

### #3.1 [By updating applications in Ubuntu by a Live CD](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-422523.html)

The following commands are not accurate according to popey at #ubuntu-uk.

I run

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/repair
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/repair
sudo chroot /mnt/repair              // after this I did not manage to run other commands    

sudo apt-get update                  // I cannot run these, I get no traffic outside
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo aptitude upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get upgrade

exit
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Missing `loop`?  Try `modprobe loop`.  This does not belong on Stack Overflow, though -- try Super User instead.

Comment: I finally reinstalled Ubuntu to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get an excellent answer by Popey at #Ubuntu-uk

**Paste from popey at Tue, 24 Nov 2009 12:04:21 +0000**

```
Repairing a stuffed up install

== Asumptions ==

 * Booted off live cd
 * Local hard disk is /dev/sda
 * Root partition is /dev/sda1
 * Home partition is /dev/sda2

== Make directories ==

$ mkdir ~/target
$ mkdir ~/target/proc
$ mkdir ~/target/dev
$ mkdir ~/target/sys
$ mkdir ~/target/home

== Mount filesystems ==

$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 ~/target
$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 ~/target/home

== Mount other bits ==

$ sudo mount -o bind /dev ~/target/dev
$ sudo mount -o bind /sys ~/target/sys
$ sudo mount -o bind /proc ~/target/proc

== Chroot into it ==

$ sudo chroot ~/target
```

I get the following in running one of the commandss

```
root@ubuntu:/# sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
```

This may be the reason why Popey's pieces of advice did not solve the problem.

Comment: I opened a thread about the problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790010/solving-ubuntus-resolve-problem-with-dpkg