# Solving Ubuntu's resolve -problem with dpkg

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dpkg

This question is based on [Popey's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/74733/fixing-x11s-startup-errors-by-xorg-conf-or-modprobe/74736#74736). I mounted my broken Ubuntu such that I can access it by Ubuntu Live CD. However, I did not manage to run one of the commands such that my X11 gets stuck at the startup.

**How can you solve the following "resolve" problem?**

```
root@ubuntu:/# sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
```

Comment: Indeed :/ Sorry for my answer ^^

Comment: Don't apologize for the answer, @Toms. It'll still be there if this gets nudged to one of the other sites, and it *is* helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `/etc/hosts` file contains something like the following.  The `127.0.0.1` line should ***not*** contain anything other than "localhost".

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu
```

or

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
x.x.x.x         ubuntu
```

(... where "x.x.x.x" is your system's IP address, and "ubuntu" is your system's hostname.)

Comment: don't do this!  for ubuntu, leave the 127.0.0.1 line alone (should list "localhost" only).  use `127.0.0.2  ubuntu` if you need it, or any other number in 127.x.x.x.

Comment: corrected the example & clarified.

Answer (score 0):

This is a false issue. You don't need to use `sudo` once you have chrooted, because you're already root.

Just use

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

without sudo, and you'll be fine.

Comment: What about if I *don't* want to be root? That's my particular issue, I want to run a `chroot`ed command with another user than root.

Comment: Use schroot for example.